# count the number of attempts from an output

Tags: linux, bash

This question is in regard to the output of the script,
because I need to know how many attempts I made..

```
## Guess the Right Number ##

#!/bin/bash
clear

while :

do

echo "enter the guessing number:"

read num

if [ $num -eq 47 ]; then

echo "That is a right number"

break

elif [ $num -le 47 ]; then

echo "print higher number"

elif [ $num -ge 47 ]; then

echo "print lower number"

fi

done
```

and the following output will be:

enter the guessing number:

23

print higher number

enter the guessing number:

34

print higher number

enter the guessing number:

45

print higher number

enter the guessing number:

47

That is a right number

How do I write code to display an extra line stating how many attempts were made to reach the correct answer?

Comment: initialize a counter, increment every time in loop and print the value after loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't so far off.

This will do it on bash incrementing a variable called `$attempts` (which starts at 1), each time the wrong answer is attempted.

The loop message uses the `$lastmsg` variable to make it simple to display the relevant prompt each time.

```
#!/bin/bash
guessno=47                                        # Set the number to guess
attempts=1                                        # Initial attempts is 1
while true;                                       # Run forever until exit
do
    clear
    echo "$lastmsg"                               # Display last message
    read -p "enter the guessing number" num
    if [[ $num -eq "$guessno" ]]; then
        echo "Correct"
        echo "It took "$attempts" attempt(s)"
        exit                                       # Exit program here
    fi
    if [[ $num -le "$guessno" ]]; then
        lastmsg="print higher number"              # Update $lastmsg
        (( attempts ++ ))
    elif [[ $num -ge "$guessno" ]]; then
        lastmsg="print lower number"               # Update $lastmsg
        (( attempts ++ ))
    fi   
done
```

Note that the entire program took place inside the endless loop, with the correct answer exiting the program directly.

Comment: Thank you so much hmedia1 that did resolve my issue... :) thanks a ton